# Python html scraping from php

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm trying to get a list of names(randomly generated from the site),

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://random-name-generator.info/random/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

#This will create a list of buyers:
names = tree.xpath('///div[@class="results"]/ol[@class="nameList"]/li/text()')

print ('Names: ', names)
```

but, I get the result like this,

```
Names:  ['\n\t\t\t\tCandace\t\t\t\t \t\t\t\tBeck\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\tIsaac\t\t\t\t \t\t\t\tZimmerman\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\tGustavo\t\t\t\t \t\t\t\tPaul\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\tHeidi\t\t\t\t \t\t\t\tOrtega\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\tYvonne\t\t\t\t \t\t\t\tSchneider\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\tArnold\t\t\t\t \t\t\t\tOwen\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\tIvan\t\t\t\t \t\t\t\tChambers\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\tTami\t\t\t\t \t\t\t\tTaylor\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\tMeghan\t\t\t\t \t\t\t\tSutton\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\tSean\t\t\t\t \t\t\t\tHuff\t\t\t\t\t\t']
```

Is there a solution to make this parsed without those \n\t\t\t\t ?

best,

Comment: there are sites that produce data like this in a friendlier format for programming (api).

Answer (score 0):

Try this I haven't tested it but it should get you started.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://random-name-generator.info/random/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

#This will create a list of buyers:
names = tree.xpath('///div[@class="results"]/ol[@class="nameList"]/li/text()')


nameClean = []

for name in names:
    name = name.replace("\t", "").replace("\n", "")
    nameClean.append(name)

print ('Names: ', nameClean)
```

Comment: thanks. But I get this error for some reason.
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: To get index and name out of names, you would need to wrap names in an `enumerate()`. You can do the same strip with the following instead of the for loop `clean_names = [ name.replace("\t","").replace("\n","") for name in names ]`

Comment: I edited and tested it and it worked for me. Try it again.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like:

```
names = [re.sub('\t|\n', '', name) for name in names]
```

You can also compile the reg-exp if speed is very important.